# Problem After upgrade

Tags: error, magento-1.9, upgrade

**The Magento CE forums is down so I am asking a question here.
I updated 'mag core' (from update manager) from 1.6 to 1.9 and now I am unable to access
both my website (wwww.lorraineperfumes.com) or my Magento Admin page.  This is the error log:**  How do I undo this???

```
2014-08-03T16:52:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include_once(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49
2014-08-03T16:52:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include_once() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49
2014-08-03T16:52:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T16:52:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T16:52:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T16:52:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include_once(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49
2014-08-03T16:52:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include_once() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49
2014-08-03T16:52:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T16:52:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T16:52:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T17:20:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:17:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:17:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:17:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:41:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:52:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:52:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-08-03T18:52:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/local:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/community:/home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core:/home/lormag/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/lormag/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Comment: I tried to follow the posted suggestion of running this SSH command and this is what happened (same as first error I received) -bash-3.2$ php compiler.php disable

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /home/lormag                                             /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 165

Fatal error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /home/lormag/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 165

Comment: Upgrades without experimenting on a dev server first till upgrade is succuessful are always expensive experiments that cost sales.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I undo this???

To undo an upgrade, you will have to manually restore your installation from a backup. There is plenty of information available on this subject.

However, I can only assume that since you had to ask how to undo this, you are not only inexperienced with doing things like restoring from a backup, you probably didn't know that you should have had a backup to begin with, so it is likely that my answer will not be of any help.

In any event, without a backup, your best option moving forward to get your store back up and running as quickly as possible is to hire someone that is able to fix this for you. The more time you spend trying to figure this out yourself, the more sales you will miss out on.

Comment: The takeaway for the day is **don't experiment on your income source**. A couple backups of both application code and database always. And dry-run any upgrade on a dev server before committing your live e-commerce server.